# How do I create my own NLTK text from a text file?

Tags: python, nltk

I'm a Literature grad student, and I've been going through the O'Reilly book in Natural Language Processing (nltk.org/book). It looks incredibly useful. I've played around with all the example texts and example tasks in Chapter 1, like concordances. I now know how many times Moby Dick uses the word "whale." The problem is, I can't figure out how to do these calculations on one of my own texts. I've found information on how to create my own corpora (Ch. 2 of the O'Reilly book), but I don't think that's exactly what I want to do. In other words, I want to be able to do

```
import nltk 
text1.concordance('yellow')
```

and get the places where the word 'yellow' is used in my text. At the moment I can do this with the example texts, but not my own.

I'm very new to python and programming, and so this stuff is very exciting, but very confusing.

Comment: This question illustrates some deep problems with the nltk documentation. I sympathize.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Found the answer myself. That's embarrassing. Or awesome.

From Ch. 3:

```
f=open('my-file.txt','rU')
raw=f.read()
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
text = nltk.Text(tokens)
```

Does the trick.

Comment: Excellent. I was just trying to answer this question myself; very glad I stumbled on your (self)answer. -- Another Literature Scholar

Comment: For this to work, I first needed to download "punkt": 
nltk.download('punkt')

Comment: What does the rU do ?

Found it:
f = open('myfile.txt', 'rU') # rU means "read", and handles line endings

Answer (score 14):

For a structured import of multiple files:

```
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader

# RegEx or list of file names
files = ".*\.txt"

corpus0 = PlaintextCorpusReader("/path/", files)
corpus  = nltk.Text(corpus0.words())
```

see: [NLTK 3 book](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html) / section 1.9

Comment: I was happy to see this, since the previous method (above) didn't work for me.  Alas, another error message.  It didn't like the line involving PlaintextCorpusReader: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 50: invalid continuation byte

Comment: to resolve utf8 error, add encoding: PlaintextCorpusReader(path, '.*', encoding='latin-1')

Answer (score 0):

If your text file is in utf8 format, try the following variation:

```
f=open('my-file.txt','r',encoding='utf8')
raw=f.read()
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
text = nltk.Text(tokens)
```